# How to implement Wake-On-Lan using WINAPI with C

Tags: c, winapi, wake-on-lan

I have the MAC address of my 2sd workstation which is under the same LAN as my primary computer.

I want to send a magic packet 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF to his MAC address. I know i must use UDP.

What i don't know is : What is the broadcast address and how can i get it from code ?

I want to do it in plain C using WinAPI.

Comment: [A special definition exists for the IP address 255.255.255.255. It is the broadcast address of the *zero network* or *0.0.0.0*, which in Internet Protocol standards stands for *this network*, i.e. the local network.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address)

Comment: Or, the subnet broadcast address, like 192.168.x.255 for subnet mask 255.255.255.0, instead of the network-wide broadcast address 255.255.255.255.